# MoveIt setup assistant symbol lookup error while loading model

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Today I wanted to load an old robot model into  the moveit_setup_assistant. I tried several models, all of which I once could easily load, but all of them failed the same way:

```
process[moveit_setup_assistant-1]: started with pid [6819]

(moveit_setup_assistant:6819): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_direction: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(moveit_setup_assistant:6819): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_direction: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
[ INFO] [1467190832.819020263]: Loaded item_table robot model.
[ INFO] [1467190832.819146906]: Setting Param Server with Robot Description
[ INFO] [1467190832.834453095]: Robot semantic model successfully loaded.
[ INFO] [1467190832.834526040]: Setting Param Server with Robot Semantic Description
[ INFO] [1467190832.858036026]: Loading robot model 'item_table'...
[ INFO] [1467190832.858102899]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1467190833.314165918]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1467190833.314333604]: OpenGl version: 3 (GLSL 1.3).
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/indigo/lib/libmoveit_setup_assistant_widgets.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4rviz20VisualizationManagerC1EPNS_11RenderPanelEPNS_22WindowManagerInterfaceEN5boost10shared_ptrIN2tf17TransformListenerEEE
================================================================================REQUIRED     process [moveit_setup_assistant-1] has died!
process has died [pid 6819, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant __name:=moveit_setup_assistant __log:=/home/marcel/.ros/log/6304d61a-3dc8-11e6-aab6-5404a6f2a4cf/moveit_setup_assistant-1.log].
log file: /home/marcel/.ros/log/6304d61a-3dc8-11e6-aab6-5404a6f2a4cf/moveit_setup_assistant-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[moveit_setup_assistant-1] killing on exit
```

I reinstalled all moveit packages, still same error. Has anybody an idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238377/moveit-setup-assistant-symbol-lookup-error-while-loading-model/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-29**:
Do you have any outstanding ROS-related updates? Binary compatibility is not always guaranteed between builds / syncs in ROS, so upgrading only parts of it can result in strange errors and failures.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2016-07-08**:
No, I installed all updates. Then, because it was still not working, I removed and reinstalled all moveit packages.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2016-07-08**:
Is it possible that this error is related to OpenGL?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-09**:
I doubt it. Sounds more like a mismatch between the main MSA binary and some of its shared libraries. The symbol demangled is: `rviz::VisualizationManager::VisualizationManager(rviz::RenderPanel*, rviz::WindowManagerInterface*, boost::shared_ptr<tf::TransformListener>)`. Are all your pkgs up2date?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-09**:
Also: what platform, how did you install ROS, compiler versions, etc.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2016-07-09**:
I think you nailed it!
Because of an issue with RVIZ some time ago, I still have it in my own workspace and therefore did not get any updates.
Will try with updated RVIZ pkg on monday!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-09**:
Yeah, as I wrote before: there is no binary compatibility guarantee between successive ROS updates, so you'll either have to not update anything *or* update everything. You can have overlays with different versions, but then you *must* rebuild whenever the `.deb`s get updated.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2016-07-11**:
Thank you, that was it. I updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was with RVIZ: I did not use the updated version because I had an older version sitting in my workspace (due to an older, already resolved issue).
When not sourcing my workspace, everything works fine.

Using the latest RVIZ version resolved the error.

---

Originally posted by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) with karma: 200 on 2016-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2017-08-02**:
Hi, I got the same issue.
What version of RVIZ works ? mine 1.11.3 crash with MoveIt
Thanks

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2017-08-15**:
i use the latest version in indigo